# How to customize card in Kanban board in GitHub Projects

Tags: github, github-projects

Can we customise the card in Kannan board? is there any plugin available?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but I will list the possibilities here anyway:

- Use Markdown
- Create/Import a Card from an issue
- Use a GitHub Application/the API in order to add automation functions(e.g. move an issue if a label has been added)
- Create custom categories (and add automation)